# Why is Heroku installing gems I don't use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I am trying to deploy our app to Heroku. It is a Rails 6/Ruby 2.6.5 app running against PostgreSQL.

For some reason Heroku installs the MySQL gem, and also it is failing trying install the Poppler gem dependencies (specifically gobject-introspection 3.4.1), even though we have removed Poppler from our Gemfile. The words Poppler and Mysql don't appear anywhere in our code.

I have done a bundle clean and saw those gems go.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: are these gems mentioned in your `Gemfile.lock`? they could be a dependency of another Gem.

Comment: If you want to push a branch that is not your local master to heroku you can do `git push heroku other_branch_name:master`. Pushing other branches than master to heroku has no effect. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code

Comment: And obviously `git push heroku master` is equal to `git push heroku master:master` and will push your master regardless of what  branch you have checked out. `git push heroku` will also do the same if you setup the remote with the `-u` option.